# Scanner for multiple characters with getCommand

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to use scanner this way to get user inputs but I'm unsure how to have multiple character input. For example with the code below if the user input `a` and enters it, it'll go into the if statement that equals `a`. Now I'd like to read more than 1 character, for example with the code below user could input `p1`, `p2`, `p3`...`p20`, etc. instead of just `p` like how it's coded below. I usually would be able to use `scan.hasNext()` but is there an equivalent one to that for my `command` variable with `getCommand` below?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = getCommand(scan);

if(command.equals("a")){
}else if(command.equals("p")){
}

private String getCommand(Scanner scan){
    System.out.print("Please enter a one or two character command: ");
    String command = null;

    if(scan.hasNext()){
        command = scan.nextLine();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Exit");
    }
    return command;
}
```

Comment: What is the method `getCommand()` from?

Comment: Why don't just tell us what kind text do you need to input exactly?

Comment: @user3437460 If it's typed input, it could be anything.

Comment: I just read the question another 5 times, and I still don't understand what OP wants.

Comment: I want to be able to input more than 1 char I have updated the OP with the command method.

Comment: @user2318083 Input more than 1 character, you can simply use `scn.nextLine()`. If you need to do it multiple times, just place the scanning of input within a loop.

Comment: try replacing if(scan.hasNext()){command = scan.nextLine();} to simply command = scan.nextLine(), from what I can see in the question that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @user3437460 I could get the first character fine, I think the issue I'm having is comparing the second and third character. For example instead of making a bunch of if else for the `command.equals("p")` how would I compare the second character? So instead of `if(command.equals("p1"))` `else if(command.equals("p2"))` `else if(command.equals("p3"))` how would I have it on one line instead? I was thinking of doing a nested if, so if the first char is `p` then it'll go in that and if the second char is `1` then do what's inside that.

Comment: You need to tell us what format of input is required. Do you intend to input everything in just one line like "`p1 p2 p3 p4`" ? You also have to tell us is your input all commencing with a "p" ?

Comment: @user3437460 `p1` would be one input, then if I put `p2` it'll be another. For that one yes, all of them commence with `p` however I have other if else that commence with other letters but they're single characters so I already have those all done. Only command that needs more than one character is the `p`

Comment: @user2318083 Look at my solution below. Be it single character or not in the input, actually it does not matter. Just capture it as String.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you probably wanted something like this.

Your "command" makes it sounds like you wanted something like the DOS command prompt receiving commands.

You can continuously prompt for inputs with a given condition. For example:

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
String cmd= "";
do{
    System.out.print("Command: ");
    cmd= scn.nextLine();
    executeCommand(cmd);
}while(!cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"));


//Create a method to execute command
public static void executeCommand(String cmd)
{
    switch(cmd){
        case "p1": //do whatever you need to do for p1
                  break;
        case "p2": //do whatever you need to do for p2
                  break;
        case "p3": //do whatever you need to do for p3 and so on..
                  break;
        default: System.out.println("Invalid command");
                  break;
    }
}
```

However, do note that the actual command prompt do not handle command this way. The command prompt are merely executing individual executable programs based on the entered executable file names.

However, if you have thousands of commands, this method can be a little inefficient. It all depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

---

There are a number of ways to handle the command. You can receive the commands (strings) directly from the command line argument in the main method as well.
`public static void main(String[] args)` <= receive and store in args array is another alternative.